# Compare two files Byte by Byte

Tags: c, file, comparison, fread

I have two binary files and I want to compare them Byte by Byte. I came up with the following code to do so:

```
int CompareFiles(char *pFname1, char *pFname2)
{
    FILE      *pFile1,*pFile2;
    long      lSize1, lSize2;               // file length
    int       i=0;
    char      tmp1, tmp2;

    pFile1 = fopen(pFname1,"r");
    pFile2 = fopen(pFname2,"r");

    // obtain file size:
    fseek (pFile1 , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize1 = ftell (pFile1);
    rewind (pFile1);

    // obtain file size:
    fseek (pFile2 , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize2 = ftell (pFile2);
    rewind (pFile2);

    if (lSize1 != lSize2) {
        printf("File sizes differ, %d vs. %d\n",lSize1,lSize2);
        return ( ERROR );
    }
    for (i=0;i<lSize1;i++) {
        fread(&tmp1, sizeof(char), 1, pFile1+i);
        fread(&tmp2, sizeof(char), 1, pFile2+i);
        if (tmp1 != tmp2) {
            printf("%x: tmp1 0x%x != tmp2 0x%x\n",i , tmp1, tmp2);
        }
    }
    return ( OK );
}
```

But for some reason, it looks like the pointer in the file doesn't advance and it keeps comparing the same Bytes to each other for the whole length of the `for` loop. Why so? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Tip: use memcmp instead of iterating through each byte: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/?kw=memcmp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
fread(&tmp1, sizeof(char), 1, pFile1+i);
fread(&tmp2, sizeof(char), 1, pFile2+i);
```

is changing the file handle for each iteration of the loop.  You should use

```
fread(&tmp1, 1, 1, pFile1);
fread(&tmp2, 1, 1, pFile2);
```

instead.  Each call to `fread` will advance the file handle's internal pointer to it's file content automatically.

Note that you also log differences in file content but fail to return an error to calling code during your `for` loop.

If you want to return as soon as you encounter a difference, use

```
for (i=0;i<lSize1;i++) {
    fread(&tmp1, 1, 1, pFile1);
    fread(&tmp2, 1, 1, pFile2);
    if (tmp1 != tmp2) {
        printf("%x: tmp1 0x%x != tmp2 0x%x\n",i , tmp1, tmp2);
        return ( ERROR ); // report error to caller
    }
}
return ( OK );
```

If you want to log all differences (this will be potentially very time consuming), use

```
int err = OK;
for (i=0;i<lSize1;i++) {
    fread(&tmp1, 1, 1, pFile1);
    fread(&tmp2, 1, 1, pFile2);
    if (tmp1 != tmp2) {
        printf("%x: tmp1 0x%x != tmp2 0x%x\n",i , tmp1, tmp2);
        err = ERROR;  // report error to caller
    }
}
return err;
```

Comment: so how do I advance the file pointer then when I want to compare each Byte? s for your note, i compare each Byte and print a message if they differ, what do ytou mean exactly?

Comment: Make sure you remove that error `pFile1+i` from your extended points